# Leaflet map wont appear

Tags: javascript, php, html, leaflet

I'm trying to use a map, but it doesn't seem to work it just shows an empty white space. I hard reseted my pc days ago, so I'm not sure if something is missing in my pc or my code is wrong, but here it is:

header.php:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
      crossorigin=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
```

main.css:

```
div.mapa{
  height: 420px;
}
```

footer.php:

```
</footer>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

      var mapa = document.getElementById('mapa');
      if(mapa) {
        var map = L.map('mapa').setView([-12.088507, -76.995052], 16);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
        L.marker([-12.088507, -76.995052]).addTo(map)
            .bindTooltip('Paris WebCamp 2020<br> Boletos disponibles.')
            .openTooltip();
      }

  });
});
```

index.php:

```
<div id="mapa" class="mapa"></div>
```

After everything... it doesnt show, it's just a blank space in my web

Comment: By the way, you should use a `load` Event, so you're sure leaflet's been loaded. It might just be in your cache already.

Comment: @StackSlave: since the Leaflet script is not loaded with async attribute (nor defer), it should block the rest of the page, in particular the app script here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IIFE is never invoked:

```js
(function () {
  // some code...
}); // Function is expressed but not invoked
```

Should be:

```js
(function () {
  // some code...
})(); // Make sure to add the final parenthesis pair
```

Just for completeness, it also works with the calling parenthesis pair just after the braces:

```js
(function () {
  // some code...
}());
```